# Colspan behaving oddly

Tags: html, css, html-table

HTML:

```
<table style="width:800px" class="space">
    <tr style="height:120px">
        <td colspan="1">1</td>
        <td colspan="2">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:100px">
        <td rowspan="2">3</td> 
        <td>4</td>
        <td rowspan="2">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:100px">
        <td>6</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr style="height:60px">
        <td colspan="2">7<td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.space {
padding:0px;
border-spacing:1px;
}
```

Im trying to make an asymetrical table, but as you see if you try the code out I cant get the "7" table row to span all the way. Colspan="2" gives me a little unwanted border, Colspan="3" gives me another cell. I got no clue how to fix this, been at it for days.

Suggestions?

Comment: You have a typo at `<td colspan="2">7<td>` which is causing two table cells to be created instead of one.

Comment: What was your desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an error in your html for starters. (you forgot to close the td, so you have 2 tds in the last row)

```
 <td colspan="2">6<td>
```

should be

```
<td colspan="3">6</td>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/4zdqM/
(td's colored red so you can see what's going on)

Comment: Oh god... Such a little mistake causing me all this trouble. Instantly noticed by somebody else than yourself, haha.. Thanks, works perfectly now